# AWS SES Suppression List

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have read that we can remove an Email Address from the ***Amazon SES Suppression List***  [from the following link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/remove-from-suppression-list.html)

But however **if we want to add an email address to the Suppression List**, what would be the procedure.

I am new to the AWS environment ,can anyone help in this ?

Answer (score 1):

Email addresses get added to the suppression list if it has "recently caused a hard bounce for any Amazon SES customer".

If you don't want SES to send an email to a particular email address, perhaps remove them from your recipient list.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is one of the step that we can remove them from our recipient list, but if we want to add an email address explicitly to our suppression list can we do  it ?

Comment: @tarunkumarSharma, no.  Your code simply must not send email to that address -- you implement this restriction yourself.  The suppression list is global and applies to all SES customers.

Comment: From Nov 2019 Amazon SES added Account-Level suppression list.